# Flink KeyedProcessFunction does not invoke on process time logic

Tags: apache-flink

I have four events

```
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 1.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T00:00:00.01Z"),
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 2.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T03:00:00.01Z"),
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 3.0 , lng = 0.0,  ts = "2018-10-16T04:00:00.01Z"),
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 4.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T06:00:00.01Z")
```

I need the output as

```
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 2.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T03:00:00.01Z")
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 4.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T06:00:00.01Z")
```

To summarise I need to get the latest record within `four hour` window. All events are keyd by `id`.

My solution involves using `KeyedProcessFunction`. My program only emits the last record as seen below.

```
UserEvent(id = "customer-1", lat = 4.0 , lng = 0.0 , ts = "2018-10-16T06:00:00.01Z")
```

The complete unit test can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/54b6c1a93427e82971db86695e5b1c03)

Comment: I didn't go through the specifics but can't you just `userEvents.keyBy(...).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(4))).maxBy(... get timestamp ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

From the unit test it appears that you intend to use event time, but to make that happen you should use

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Furthermore, what is your question?